# how to send image on twitter before ios5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, twitter

I'm creating an application that has integration with Twitter .. and wanted to know what have to do to create a button to add an image of the device in the tweet.and also wanted to know which framework to use it and also where the code because my app should be compatible with ios4 too.

First of all is it possible to send image on twitter before ios5?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can upload image to twitter.
2. Have a look at this blog article on [integrating twitter into your applications](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/); and
3. This one about [adding twitpic to your application](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/02/23/adding-twitpic-to-your-application/) to upload images

Answer (score 0):

use `sharekit`. Refer [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oauth for this sending.it is compatible with ios4.acct123 is Oauth account

```
- (IBAction)composeTweet:(id)sender
{
   // Build a twitter request
NSString *resultprofileUrl= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];

tweets = [NSMutableArray array];


// Posting image and text to twitpic............


ASIFormDataRequest *req = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitpic.com/2/upload.json"]];
[req addRequestHeader:@"X-Auth-Service-Provider" value:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"];

[req addRequestHeader:@"X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization"
                value:[acct123 oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"GET"
                                             andUrl:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"
                                          andParams:nil]];

[req setData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview3.image, 0.8) forKey:@"media"];
[req setPostValue:@"YourKey" forKey:@"key"];
[req setPostValue:tweetPost.text forKey:@"message"];
[req startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"Got HTTP status code from TwitPic: %d", [req responseStatusCode]); 
NSLog(@"Response string: %@", [req responseString]);
NSDictionary *twitpicResponse = [[req responseString] JSONValue];
NSLog(@"image url: %@", twitpicResponse);
url1 = [twitpicResponse valueForKey:@"url"];
NSLog(@"url=%@",url1);
if (url1 == nil) {
    url1 = @"";
}
[req release];
NSString *resultUrl = [[NSString alloc]init];
if(reply_tweet_flag != 1)
{
    resultUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tweetPost.text,url1];
}
else
{
    resultUrl= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tweetPost.text];
}
NSLog(@"URL>>>>%@",resultUrl);
NSString *postUrl = @"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json";
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc]
                               initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postUrl]];

NSMutableDictionary *postInfo = [NSMutableDictionary
                                 dictionaryWithObject:resultUrl
                                 forKey:@"status"];


for (NSString *key in [postInfo allKeys]) {
    [request setPostValue:[postInfo objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
}

[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization"
                    value:[acct123 oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"POST"
                                                 andUrl:postUrl
                                              andParams:postInfo]];

[request startSynchronous];

NSLog(@"Status posted. HTTP result code: %d", request.responseStatusCode);


if (reply_tweet_flag == 1) {
    reply_tweet_flag = 0;
    [self refresh];

}
if([tweetPost.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    UIAlertView *message1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                       message:@"Check the message"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [message1 show];
    message1.tag=1;

}
else{
    [tweetPost setText:@""];
    imageview3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

    UIAlertView *message1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                       message:@"Post was send succesfully"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [message1 show];
    message1.tag=1;
}
```

}